# Invoke value event handler only on value change in Firebase

Tags: firebase

Is there a way to invoke the `value` event handler only on value change in `Firebase`? If I just add the `value` event handler without any special code, it will be called once on reading the initial value and then on any value change. I want to avoid invoking the event handler on reading the initial value.

One of the use cases where I need this functionality is that I am working on an app where user can add tasks for some other users. The other users can either accept or reject a task. There is a server which is monitoring these tasks on `Firebase` and it sends a push notification to the creator of the task whenever a user accepts or rejects a task i.e. whenever there is a change in the status of task.

I have tried two solutions.

Solution 1:

Have a map and add an entry to the map when the `value` event handler is called if it is not already present and if the the entry is present, then do the work required on value change. This solution works but I need this in several different cases and I have to create this map in all such cases and I didn't find it to be a convenient solution.

Solution 2:

Add the `value` event handler like this

```
ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  console.log('Initial call ', this.initialCall); 
  if(!this.initialCall) {
    // Do work
  } else {
    this.initialCall = false;
  }
}, {initialCall: true})  // {initialCall: true} is the context which is provided as this in the event handler
```

Here my thinking was that I can check if the event handler is called for the initial value by checking if `this.initialCall` is set to `true`. If it is, then set the `this.initialCall` to `false` and then in the subsequent invocations, `this.initialCall` should be `false` and I can do the work required for a value change. Using this solution what I observed was that the `this.initialCall` was `undefined` the first time the handler is called and then it was set to `true` and then it was `true` for all value change event handler invocations for all the tasks, not just the one for which it was set to true.

With regards to solution 2, I am not a JS expert and it is possible that due to some gap in my JS knowledge, I am doing something wrong due to which it doesn't work as I expected.

Please let me know if you have an idea/solution which can be used to call the `value` event handler only on value change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `value` event in Firebase is invoked immediately with the current value and then whenever the value changes. If you only care abut when the value changes, you can simply ignore the initial event:

```
var isInitialValue = true;
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (isInitialValue) {
    isInitialValue = false;
  }
  else {
    // TODO: handle subsequent changes
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was trying to overcomplicate the solution when the solution is so much simpler. On a side note, do you see any problem with my attempted second solution. I thought I could use the `context` to pass on some data to the event handler and use it inside but I didn't receive the data in the event handler. If you want me to open a different question for this problem, please let me know.